# Exclude Images from Mobile Redirect on htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using htaccess to create a mobile redirect for my website. Basically it changes mysite.com to m.mysite.com. In the process it also changes the url of images. How can I prevent that? Below is the code I am using.

```
    # turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
# only detect smart phone devices if we are not on mobile site
# to prevent redirect looping
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.easydestination.net$
# a bunch of smart phone devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "windows ce|epoc|opera|mini|nitro" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "audiovox|blackberry|ericsson,"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|dange"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\."[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC,OR]
# redirect google mobile bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "googlebot-mobile"[NC]
# if the request is from any one of the above devices
# redirect to mobile site
RewriteRule .? http://m.easydestination.net%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this, line before the last RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
```

To exclude all files with .gif .jpeg .jpg .png
Do not forget after to use absolute links for those images.